# Raw and Generic List

Tags: java

This is a code just to know what is wrong and what is right.

```
public class JavaApplication5 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

  List l=new ArrayList<String>();//Line 1

  List<Object> x=new ArrayList<String>();//Line 2


}

 }
```

In the above line 1 is working fine but line 2 gives me compilation error. Can you tell me why?

Are not `List` and `List<Object>` equivalent? Either both should be wrong or both should be correct.

Comment: You are using different types in List on left side you have Object and on the right side you are instancing it as a Strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: what is difference between List and List<Object>

Comment: Raw types bypass generic type checks, deferring the catch of unsafe code to runtime. So `List` becomes `List<String>` at runtime, whereas `List<Object>` is already known at compile time.  Check out Oracle's tutorial on [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the same Type in the both place :

```
List<Object> x = new ArrayList<String>();
//----^-------------------------^--------
```

So you have to option to solve your problem :

One don't set any type in your `ArrayList`

```
List<Object> x = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or set the same type :

```
List<Object> x = new ArrayList<Object>();
//or
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither posted option. For a `List` of `String`(s), since Java 7, you can use the diamond operator - like,

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, the older

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
```

is still legal.

Your first option is a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), and your second option (if it were legal) makes a `List` that can contain any type of `Object` (not just `String`).